# One View and Multiple Domains/Controllers in Grails

Tags: grails, model-view-controller, separation-of-concerns

I have 2 domains: user & item + corresponding controllers. There is no link (domains don't have a relationship) between user & item. I need to create a view that displays information from both user & item. For example list all users and items in a single view. How can I achieve that? What would be the right approach?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grails uses a convention but that convention can easily be broken.

```
class SomeController {

   def list() {
      def users = Users.list()
      def items = Item.list()
      [users: users, items: items]
   }
}
```

grails-app/views/some/list.gsp

```
<ul>
  <g:each in="${users}">
    <li>${it.firstName}</li>
  </g:each>
</ul>

<ul>
  <g:each in="${items}">
    <li>${it.name}</li>
  </g:each>
</ul>
```

Comment: In case I am making dashboard where I need to display data from multiple domain, I don't have a choice but to break MVC? Is there any other solution? Please explain. Thank you!

Comment: How is this breaking MVC?  You have a Model (Item, User), you have a View (list.gsp) and you have controller (SomeController).  Or in your case, maybe DashboardController.  The solution I provided is perfectly fine and doesn't break MVC.  You should maybe read up on the pattern a bit more.

Comment: Do you have any other articles - more in depth?